# Is a pointer copy necessary when I modify, alter and `delete` the original pointer?

Tags: c++, pointers

[Rao (2012, p. 180, listing 8.9)](https://books.google.nl/books?id=JUT-rDb5R1UC&pg=PR2&lpg=PR2&dq=siddhartha%20rao%202012%20pearson&source=bl&ots=6VOqh9muuC&sig=hjLUu6DKfi_QHicsKtjvQEmOSRU&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj41ab_j8LUAhXRL1AKHbr-DHAQ6AEITzAJ#v=onepage&q=siddhartha%20rao%202012%20pearson&f=false) says "The reason you create a copy in Line 10 is so that the loop modifies the pointer being used via the increment operator (`++`). The original pointer returned by new needs to be stored intact for the corresponding `delete[]` in Line 26 needs to be invoked using the address returned by new and not any random value".

```
0: #include <iostream>
1: using namespace std;
2:
3: int main()
4: {
5: cout << “How many integers you wish to enter? “;
6: int InputNums = 0;
7: cin >> InputNums;
8:
9: int* pNumbers = new int [InputNums]; // allocate requested integers
10: int* pCopy = pNumbers;
11:
12: cout<<“Successfully allocated memory for “<<InputNums<< “ integers”<<endl;
13: for(int Index = 0; Index < InputNums; ++Index)
14: {
15: cout << “Enter number “<< Index << “: “;
16: cin >> *(pNumbers + Index);
17: }
18:
19: cout << “Displaying all numbers input: “ << endl;
20: for(int Index = 0, int* pCopy = pNumbers; Index < InputNums; ++Index)
21: cout << *(pCopy++) << “ “;
22:
23: cout << endl;
24:
25: // done with using the pointer? release memory
26: delete[] pNumbers;
27:
28: return 0;
29: }
```

**Is the `pCopy` really necessary? What am I missing?**
In the modified example below, I do not use it and `delete[]` seem to work fine.

```
#include <iostream>    
using namespace std;

int main()
{

    cout << "How many integers do you want? " << endl;
    int InputN = 0;
    cin >> InputN;

    int* pNumbers = new int [InputN];

    cout << "allocated memory for  " << InputN << " integers"  << endl;

    for (int Idx = 0; Idx < InputN; Idx++) {
        cout << "enter number for index " << Idx << endl;
        cin >> *(pNumbers + Idx);
    }

    cout << "Display all input numbers: "  << endl;


    for (int Idx = 0; Idx < InputN + 2; ++Idx) {
        cout << "integer with index: " <<  Idx << " has  value " << *(pNumbers + Idx) << " and pointer: " << pNumbers + Idx << endl;
        //cout << pNumbers - 50000 << " points to " << *(pNumbers - 50000) << endl;
        }

    delete[] pNumbers;

    cout << "after the delete: " << endl;
    for (int Idx = 0; Idx < InputN + 2; ++Idx) {
        cout << "integer with index: " <<  Idx << " has  value " << *(pNumbers + Idx) << " and pointer: " << pNumbers + Idx << endl;
        //cout << pNumbers - 50000 << " points to " << *(pNumbers - 50000) << endl;
        }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Wall of code, please post a [MCVE]

Comment: Yes. For the reasons given in the quote.

Comment: Your version doesn't modify `pNumbers`, so it doesn't need a copy.

Comment: Declare as `int* const pNumbers` to catch accidental modifications, otherwise you're safe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the following situation

```
{
  type* ptr = new type[size];      // line A
  /*
     some code, for example
     ptr++;                        // legal but dangerous/bad
  */
  delete[] ptr;                    // line B
}
```

the value of the variable `ptr`, i.e. the address pointed to, must be the same in lines `A` and `B`. Otherwise, this is undefined behaviour and results in a crash (if you're lucky). In your second code listing, you don't use a pointer variable to loop over the elements, but an index. So, the original pointer was never changed and you satisfied the condition.

There are several ways to **ensure** that this requirement is satisfied.

1. You can declare the pointer to be `const`.

   ```
   {
     type * const ptr = new type[size];  // not: type const*ptr
     // ptr++;                           // illegal: would give a compiler error
     delete[] ptr;
   }
   ```
2. You can use a [smart pointer](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr)

   ```
   {
     std::unique_ptr<type[]> ptr = new type[size];
     /* some code */
   }   // memory is automatically freed at end of scope of ptr
   ```
3. You can use a container, such as [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)

   ```
   {
     std::vector<type> vec(size);
     /* some code */
   }   // memory is automatically freed at end of scope of ptr
   ```

The last option is the most convenient, as it also allows you to change the amount of memory allocated, or to add elements beyond the initially allocated memory (when the vector automatically re-allocates and expands).